# Using Count to get number out of total (ex: 2 of 10, 3 of 10)

Tags: php

I want to be able to show the number of an image out of the total number images contained in an album (one album per artist). Example: Album 2 of 10. Then going to the next image we would get Album 3 of 10 and so on. I can get the total number by using a function **get_count** and then on my HTML page calling the function and a **foreach** statement. However, I do not know how to write the code to get the individual nos. Code used:-

```
<?php
function get_count($artist_id) {
  $artist_id = (int)$artist_id;
  $count = array();
  $count_query = mysql_query("
      SELECT `image_album_id`, `artist_id`, COUNT(`image_album_id`) as `image_count` 
      FROM `album_images`
      WHERE `artist_id`=$artist_id AND `member_id`=".$_SESSION['member_id']);
  While ($count_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($count_query)) {
    $count[] = array(
        'id' => $count_row['image_album_id'],
        'album' =>  $count_row['artist_id'],
        'count' => $count_row['image_count']
        );
  }
  return $count;
}
?>

<?php
$count = get_count($artist_id);
foreach ($count as $count){
  echo '',$count['count'],'';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in reusing the same variable name `$count` for an array and a scalar vairable:

```
$count = get_count($artist_id);
```

`$count`is now an array.

```
foreach ($count as $count){
```

but `$count` has now been made a scalar variable, wiping out the array.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I am still left with the original problem however.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<?php
function get_count($artist_id) {
$artist_id = (int)$artist_id;
$count = array();
$count_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_album_id`, `artist_id`, COUNT
(`image_album_id`) as `image_count` 
FROM `album_images`
WHERE `artist_id`=$artist_id AND `member_id`=".$_SESSION['member_id']);
$count_img_row=1;
While ($count_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($count_query)) {
$count[] = array(
'id' => $count_row['image_album_id'],
'album' =>  $count_row['artist_id'],
'count' => $count_row['image_count'],
'image_ord'=>$count_img_row
);
$count_img_row++;
}
return $count;
}
?>

<?php
$count = get_count($artist_id);
foreach ($count as $imgcount){
echo $imgcount['image_ord']." of ".$imgcount['count'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but no joy. I only get the same number for every img. This number is the same as whatever is set at $count_img_row. So now I have 1 of 10 no matter what img is showing.

Comment: Hi, Posts seem to not be in order. I repeat my comment on the latest post.  " Hi, Well significant progress. The result is now as follows:- Album 1 of Album 2 of Album 3 of.................Album 14 of 14. This occurs for every img shown. Thanks."

Comment: Hi, additional info. Made error in comment. Total_imgs is not echoing out. If I do a print_r($imgcount), I see all the elents with their correct data.

Answer (score 0):

then Try like this

```
<?php
function get_count($artist_id) {
$artist_id = (int)$artist_id;
$count = array();
$count_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_album_id`, `artist_id`
FROM `album_images`
WHERE `artist_id`=$artist_id AND `member_id`=".$_SESSION['member_id']);
$count_img_row=1;
$total_imgs=mysql_num_rows($count_query);
While ($count_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($count_query)) {
$count[] = array(
'id' => $count_row['image_album_id'],
'album' =>  $count_row['artist_id']
);
$count_img_row++;
}
return $count;
}
?>

<?php
$count = get_count($artist_id);
foreach ($count as $imgcount){
echo $imgcount['image_ord']." of ".$total_imgs;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Well significant progress. The result is now as follows:-

Comment: Hi, The result is now as follows:- Album 1 of Album 2 of Album 3 of.................Album 14 of 14. This occurs for every img shown. Thanks." Additional info. Made error in comment. Total_imgs is not echoing out. If I do a print_r($imgcount), I see all the elements with their correct data.